# Java AWT Unique IDs for Components

Tags: java, accessibility, awt, uuid

Is there anything in Java AWT that has a unique id for each component? I need it to be similar to the [AutomationId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.automationid.aspx) in the UI Automation library from C#. It just needs to be unique among siblings. It doesn't need to be globally unique. I just need it so that I can save the path to a GUI component while it's running at some point, and then if I restart the application at a different time, I can find the component.

Is this possible using Java AWT?

Comment: if you need unique amongst the siblings (Only), `int zOrder = Container.getComponentZOrder()`, you can access the component by `Container.getComponent(zOrder)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any identifier, but usually the layout depends on the order of the components, so you can identify a component by its index in its container's `getComponents` array.

Comment: Does this stay unique if additional components get added during an event handler, but the current component hasn't been changed at all?

Comment: @Jonathan, unless you call `Container.setComponentZOrder` or remove components, it will remain the same since the components are added at the end.